# Deactivate EMFText Error reporting like "Syntax error on token "public (public)""

Tags: java, emftext

I use eclipse Neon.3 / Oxygen and installed some plugin ([JaMoPP](http://www.jamopp.org/index.php/JaMoPP)) which for some reason needs EMFText. Afterwards some Java classes (most are ok) get strange errors like

```
 - Syntax error on token "public (public)", "EOF" expected line 21  EMFText Problem
 - Syntax error on token "@ (@)", "EOF" expected line 21    EMFText Problem
```

Why is EMFText doing this? Is there a way to disable EMFText? I looked in Preferences (e.g. Validation) but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Found parts of an answer to deactive it: *Configure Contents* in the Problems View. It filters the error message from the Problems view however the errors in the Package Explorer and the java classes itself are still there.

[image: Configure Contents]